# Ghost variable "idle" in terminal/cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, posix, python-idle

I cannot figure out where, how, or why the variable "idle" has been set.

- It is not in an alias
- It isn't in my .bashrc file
- It isn't in my PATH
- It isn't a user-entered variable, because it doesn't show up when I execute this: `( set -o posix ; set ) | less`

but, when I type `cygstart idle` somehow the program still starts.  Why is this?

something that is also curious is that when I execute just `idle`, i.e. without the cygstart command, it attempts to execute a python file.  Any ideas what might be going on?

Perhaps I  am looking for suggestions about how to investigate, since I realize that there might be other problems specific to my machine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 3.4, PSF CPython Windows installers put /Scripts in the pythonxy directory. Pip and easy-install are pre-installed in Scripts.  When pip is used to install packages, associated executables are put in the corresponding /Scripts. If pythonxy is the default python installation, pythonxy/Scripts is added to the system PATH and idle.bat is added.  (At least, this is what happened on my machine.)  So yes, `command prompt> idle` should work as you describe, at least for 3.4.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a variable. IDLE is the name of a Python IDE.

You can launch it either directly or through Cygwin.

[cygstart](https://gist.github.com/charlesroper/317713) can be given the name of a file or program. If you give it the name of a program, it will run it.

Comment: I know it is  an IDE.  but the word "idle" isn't automatically set as a variable when it is installed.  something must have set it as a variable.

Comment: Why do you think it's a variable?

Comment: Because when you install other programs, the nameo of the program doesn't automatically become a variable.  e.g. nothing happens when I type `winword` in the terminal (alone).  but, like I said in my question, if I execute `idle` alone, then it attempts to execute a python file.